# Flutter http.response doesn't get any response

Tags: android, http, flutter, dart

i'm trying to get a simple response from http.Response. My code was working a few days ago and the only change from then to now was my location.

```
[...]
  http.Response resp = await http.get(
      Uri.encodeFull('$apiUrl/tblColMain'),
      headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json"
      }
  );

  print(resp);

  var data = json.decode(resp.body);

  print(data);
```

This code doesn't print anything and shows no errors, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: did it send anything to server?

Comment: no, and I don't know why.

Comment: put break point and debug, see it stop at which line.

Comment: sorry, I'm kinda new to flutter, how exactly do I do this?

Comment: which ide are you using?

Comment: Android Studio.

Comment: This will guide you how to debug. https://www.strv.com/blog/debugging-in-android-studio-as

Comment: Your code looks to be working fine, and it hits Postman Echo just fine, I think the problem is on your API side of things.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, I solved the problem. Apparently my SDK was not working properly so I emulated it the app in my own physical phone and it worked. If anyone knows the reason for this I'd like to know. cya!